# Using conditional selector for display none elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have 5 divs(say A,B,C,D,E) stacked alongside each other in flex-box layout. One element(B) gets a css value of display:none. I want to add a css rule such that when i can select C when B is display:none. Is it Possible?

Comment: Not with CSS...no! You can't selector an element based on it's `display:property` (unless that is in a `style` attribute in the HTML). You'll need JS.

Comment: To clarify, if the div has `style="display:none"`, you can use `div[style*='display:none']+div` to target the next div. If, on the other hand, the style is in the stylesheet, with `(whatever selector) {display:none;}` then you can target the next div by using the same selector and `+div` behind it for the next one.